# Inserting an ID from one table into another when a new record is inserted

Tags: php, mysql, insert

I have a form, which contains an employees personal information. I update the form, and it inserts into a table, called `employee_info`. It updates the table with the details and inserts a NEW ID(`employee_id`). In my database, I have another table called `department_info`, and the field which is relevant is `department_id`. This is the php markup, for inserting data into the database:

```
$sql_data_array = array('employee_firstname' => $employee_firstname); //other variables go here

if (ACCOUNT_DOB == 'true') $sql_data_array['driver_dob'] = tep_date_raw($driver_dob);

tep_db_perform(TABLE_EMPLOYEES, $sql_data_array);

$employee_id = tep_db_insert_id();
```

What I need to do is, when the form is updated, and data is inserted into the `employee_info` table, I need it to insert a new id for `employee_id`(which is already happening), and also to insert the `department_id` into the `employee_info` table.

The `department_id` is used to login, and I want to show a list of the employees, which belong to the department. Can anyone tell me how I would do this?

Comment: I would recommend using a trigger rather than coding it in php. I'm not going to write your trigger, but I'm just giving you something to consider.

Comment: @Scotch, I think that mixing business logic with database is a bad idea. We should keep things simple and clear as possible. What will happen, if you will need to change MySQL database for Oracle or NoSQL?

Comment: Mixing business logic with a database is a bad idea? So....what are triggers for? What are constraints for?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

When you insert with PHP, most of the implementations return so called last insert id. This is a value of AUTO_INCREMENT column.

Even if your implementation does not support it, there should be a function that returns it.

**EDIT:**
From your update, this seems to be osCommerce. The problem with your code is that method tep_db_perform is used to insert one or MORE elements. What will happen, if you insert 2 rows? But in simple case, use tep_db_insert_id(), it should return last id.

Comment: I have include the coding for inserting into the employee table, could you please show the code, for your answer?

Answer (score 0):

php function mysqli_insert_id retrieves the ID generated for an AUTO_INCREMENT column by the previous query (usually INSERT). Get this id and use it in other tables.